# Convert conditional opening html elements into haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I want to convert the following erb into haml.

```
<% if content_for?(:sidebar) %>
  <div id="right-column" class="col-lg-2">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked content-bottom-padding">
      <%= yield :sidebar %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="left-column" class="col-lg-10 content-bottom-padding">
<% else %>
  <div class="col-lg-12 content-bottom-padding">
<% end %>
   LOADS OF CODE     
</div>
```

Ofcourse you can just start converting it:

```
- if content_for?(:sidebar)
  #right-column.col-lg-2
    %ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked.content-bottom-padding= yield :sidebar
      #left-column.col-lg-10.content-bottom-padding
- else
  .col-lg-12.content-bottom-padding
```

but the large block of code is not evaluated inside the div. So how to solve this DRY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial tag output is one of the times Haml is less useful than erb. Here’s one possibility, it sets the ID to `left-column` only if it’s sidebar content:

```
-if content_for? :sidebar
  #right-column.col-lg-2
    %ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked.content-bottom-padding=yield :sidebar
%div.col-lg-10.content-bottom-padding{id: content_for?(:sidebar) ? 'left-column' : ''}
  -# LOADS OF CODE
```

You could also include the `LOADS OF CODE` in a partial and just include it under each tag.

Answer (score 2):

Can you include the "LOADS OF CODE" in a partial?

```
- if content_for?(:sidebar)
  #right-column.col-lg-2
    %ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked.content-bottom-padding= yield :sidebar
  #left-column.col-lg-10.content-bottom-padding
    = render :partial => "loads_of_code"
- else
  .col-lg-12.content-bottom-padding
    = render :partial => "loads_of_code"
```